# How can I load content on page with a change in URL in the same component in angular?

Tags: angular, url, router

I am trying to get a page to load some content upon URL change, within the same component.

> myComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.router.events.subscribe(res=> {
    if (this.router.url.split('?')[0].split("/").pop() === 'invitations'){
      console.log('do something');
    }
  }
}
```

> myModule.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
           { 
             path: 'fancy_app', 
             component: myComponent,
             children:[
               {path: 'invitations', component: myComponent}
             ]
           }
];
```

When I do this, and when I try to access the route: fancy_app/invitations for the first time, I notice that the 'do something' does not load. However, when I click on the link again it works. So I guess the ngOnInit is not the place for this? How do I ensure that It loads the first time I visit the URL?

Comment: Instead of doing this, why don't you just subscribe to the process that is triggering the change in URL in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I put it in the constructor it worked. Still not clear why this does not work on ngOnInit. As I understand, the ngOnInit is called after the constructor has instantiated the class. I was trying to avoid using the constructor. Can someone tell my why ngOnInit did not work the first time I tried to access the URL though?